# WebDAV search on Integer data type

Tags: webdav, exchange-server-2003

I have a WebDAV query which search for e-mails on an Exchange 2003 server on field 'TestField' with the value '3'. This field contains data of the type Integer (an another application set this field with data type OlUserPropertyType.olInteger).

```
SELECT "TestField" FROM "http://server/exchange/mailbox/mialbox" WHERE "TestField" = 3
```

I received always a "Bad Request (400)". On another fields with another data types (string) is works.

What is wrong in these? Must I cast the value but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Casting is the solution.

```
WHERE CAST("TestField" AS "int") = 3
```